# Net core 3.0 - signing jwt with secp256k1 - bitcoin elliptic curve

Tags: c#, cryptography, jwt, bitcoin

Is there a way to use bitcoin/ethereum elliptic curve to sign JWT token with the code like this:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

SecurityTokenDescriptor tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = claimsIdentity,
    Expires = this.GetExpiry(),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(this._jwtConfig.Key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
    Issuer = this._jwtConfig.Issuer,
    Audience = this._jwtConfig.Audience,
    NotBefore = DateTime.UtcNow,
    IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow
};

SecurityToken securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

return tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
```

At the moment object `SigningCredentials` has to be created, but `SecurityAlgorithms` does not support secp256k1. I can sign with ordinary ecdsa256 but looks like secp256k1 is not supported? Are there any custom made implementations done?